# Do I have to remove open drivers to switch to fglrx?

Tags: drivers, package-management, fglrx, ati

Do I have to uninstall open source drivers which are in Ubuntu by default before installing `fglrx`?

Comment: No you don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Uri Herrera said, no you don't have to.

Comment: This deserved to be a full answer.